# Move a Keras/tensorflow model from Linux to Windows

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have used keras (with tensorflow backend) on a Linux VM and have trained and saved that model on my Linux VM. Now I have a requirement to use that model on a Windows machine. Is there some way of exporting that model to some sort of cross-platform format so that I can use code on my Windows machine to import and save it for later use there?

Comment: I know this isn't helpful - but this kind of problem is why just biting the bullet and going full linux is something worth considering. It was working with Kuberetes and containerisation that got me to finally switch. But the issue I had there was more building containers on Windows.

Comment: That said - could you build your model as on a docker container, from your linux environment, then run the container on docker on windows?

Comment: model.save(''something.hdf5") is already a cross-platform format that you can load in Windows. HDF5 is cross-platform.